# TSQL Cast the sum as Money

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum, currency

Using SQL Server 2008, I am trying to get the return of some of these columns to come back as $xxx,xxx.xx

This is the query that I am using (this query then some updates just to calculate the numbers and select `##tempshow` at the end)

```
SELECT 
    CASE GROUPING(s.StoreID) WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE s.StoreID END [StoreID],
    CASE GROUPING(p.VendorID) WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE p.VendorID END [VendorID],
    SUM(d.Quantity) AS [UnitSold],
    CAST(SUM(d.amount * d.quantity) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Amount, 
    CAST(SUM(d.Discount) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Discount,
    CAST(SUM((d.Amount * d.Quantity - d.Discount)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS ExtSold,
    CAST(SUM(d.Cost * d.Quantity) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Cost,
    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Profit,
    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS OnHand,
    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS OnHandRetail,
    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS OnHandCost,
    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS ReceivedCost,
    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS ReceivedRetail,
    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS ReceivedQty,
    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Margin,
    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS TurnOver,
    CAST(0 AS INTEGER) AS OnOrder 
INTO
    ##tempshow
FROM 
    RPTrs s,
    RPTrsd d,
    RPIv i,
    RPProducts p
WHERE 
    s.ReceiptNO = d.ReceiptNO and 
    s.StoreID = d.StoreID and 
    i.UPC = d.UPC and 
    i.StoreID = d.StoreID and 
    p.ProductID = i.IVProduct and 
    s.StoreID = '01' and
    s.TRSDate > GETDATE()-20 and 
    p.Service = 0 
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS((s.StoreID,p.VendorID),())
```

Which returns :
[image]

I have tried

`CAST(SUM(d.amount * d.quantity) AS MONEY) AS Amount,`

and

`SUM(CAST((d.amount * d.quantity) AS MONEY)) AS Amount,`

Expected output (plus the other columns same as this `Amount` column):

```
  |StoreID | VendorID | UnitSold | Amount
---------------------------------------------
1 | 01     | 0000     | 0        | $0.00
2 | 01     | am       | 62       | $6,275.00
3 | 01     | AO       | 58       | $18,964.00
4 | 01     | payless  | 6        | $1,383.36
5 |        |          | 126      | $26,622.36
```

I need the `Amount, Discount, ExtSold, Cost, Profit, OnHandRetail, OnHandCost, ReceivedCost, ReceivedRetail` to be in the money format

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing _data type_ and _format_.  Formatting, e.g. adding a currency symbol, thousands separators and a radix point, is better left to your application.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that as it's just a simple reporting function within the software and just takes the query and outputs what is within the query

Comment: @JohnZ: Could that function be replaced with a slightly more complex one then? Really, even though it is possible to achieve what you want in T-SQL, it is the presentation level that should care about formatting. The database should only care about providing data in this case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is something that should be done on the presentation layer, but if you need to do this in sql you can use:

```
'$'+convert(varchar(50), CAST(amount as money), -1) amount
```

Here is an example:

```
;with cte (amount)
as
(
    select 123254578.00 union all
    select 99966.00 union all
    select 0.00 union all
    select 6275.00 union all 
    select 18964.00 union all 
    select 1383.36 union all
    select 26622.36
)
select '$'+convert(varchar(50), CAST(amount as money), -1) amount
from cte
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11314). This returns:

```
|          AMOUNT |
-------------------
| $123,254,578.00 |
|      $99,966.00 |
|           $0.00 |
|       $6,275.00 |
|      $18,964.00 |
|       $1,383.36 |
|      $26,622.36 |
```

Note: This will be much easier in SQL Server 2012 because you can use [`FORMAT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
;with cte (amount)
as
(
    select 123254578.00 union all
    select 99966.00 union all
    select 0.00 union all
    select 6275.00 union all 
    select 18964.00 union all 
    select 1383.36 union all
    select 26622.36
)
select '$'+FORMAT(amount,'#,0.0000') amount
from cte
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3214)

Comment: bluefeet to the rescue once again. Thank you so much, your `'$'+convert(varchar(50), CAST(amount as money), -1) amount` worked like a charm

Comment: @bonh It adds the commas to the numeric value.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to bluefeet's answer, the FORMAT function available in SQL 2012 could be done like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(12345.6789, 'C', 'en-us')
```

The C means currency, and the last argument is culture. The culture is important if you want your application to be multilingual, because it takes care of things like dollar (or euro) signs, and the thousands separator. For instance:

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(12345.6789, 'C', 'en-us') as "USA", 
FORMAT(12345.6789, 'C', 'fr-ca') as "French Canada", 
FORMAT(12345.6789, 'C', 'fr-fr') as "French France",
FORMAT(12345.6789, 'C', 'hi-in') as "Hindi India"
```

Will give this result:

```
USA            French Canada        French France     Hindi India
-----------    -------------        --------------    --------------
$12,345.68     12 345,68 $          12 345,68 €       ₹ 12,345.68
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: How to remove sign?